# echo backspace inside string

Tags: php, string, trim, strstr, backspace

Pretty simple but I'm looking for the easiest way (HEX?) and it's not working...

I want to add to the string backspaces (delete last character)...

Here is my simple code :

```
<?php

    echo '<br>Delete me!!!'."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8"."\x8";

?>
```

Small tweak needed here ;)

Comment: Do you want to print `\x8`?

Comment: No just simple backslashes (delete last character) so echo '123'.chr(8).chr(8).chr(8); will echo nothing... :)

Comment: Your question is unclear, please improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*backspace* is a special character that is interpreted by editors and various text input boxes as a request to remove the character before the cursor. The *backspace* character itself has no magical powers, it cannot make disappear something that was already displayed.

If you need to remove some characters from a string in PHP you can use **substring()**, **str_replace()**, **preg_replace()** or other string handling function.

For example, you can ignore the last 3 characters from a string like this:

```
echo(substr('blah-blah', 0, -3));
```